Converse of "Function.HasLeftInverse.injective" constructively
In Lean4, there is a constructive theorem:
theorem Function.HasLeftInverse.injective{α : Sort u₁} {β : Sort u₂} {f : α → β} : Function.HasLeftInverse f → Function.Injective f

which proves:
If a function $f$ has a left inverse, then $f$ is injective.
(The theorem is found here: Mathlib/Logic/Function/Defs)
Is the converse also provable in a constructive way? If so, would it help obtain a constructive proof of the following theorem, which is marked as nonconstructive:
noncomputable def Fintype.ofInjective{α : Type u_1} {β : Type u_2} [Fintype β] (f : α → β) (H : Function.Injective f) : Fintype α

(This theorem (definition?) is named "Fintype.ofInjective", found here: Mathlib/Data/Fintype/Basic)

The converse of Function.HasLeftInverse.injective is false because the unique map ∅ → β is injective but has no left inverse when β is inhabited because there are no maps β → ∅. You could try to save the theorem by requiring that α be inhabited, but that will not do because the theorem is classical.
In fact, if the theorem you are asking for holds, then excluded middle follows. Too see this, let $p \in \mathsf{Prop}$ be any proposition, and define $f : 1 + \{\_ \in 1 \mid p\} \to 1 + 1$ by
\begin{align*}
f(\mathsf{inl} \, \_) &= \mathsf{inl}\, () \\
f(\mathsf{inr} \, \_) &= \mathsf{inr}\, ()
\end{align*}
The domain of $f$ is inhabited and $f$ is injective, therefore by the alleged theorem it has a right inverse $g$. Either $g(\mathsf{inr}\,()) = \mathsf{inr}\,()$ or $g(\mathsf{inr}\,()) = \mathsf{inl}\,()$. In the first case $p$ holds, and in the second $\neg p$. Here is the Lean proof:
import Mathlib.Logic.Function.Defs

universe u₁ u₂

/- Auxiliary map used in the theorem below-/
def f (p : Prop) : Unit ⊕ {_u: Unit // p} → Unit ⊕ Unit
| .inl _ => .inl ()
| .inr _ => .inr ()

/- The auxliary map is injective -/
lemma f.injective (p : Prop) : Function.Injective (f p) := by
  unfold f
  rintro (u|u) (⟨v,H⟩|⟨v,H⟩) <;> simp

/-- If every injection from an inhabited type has a left inverse,
    then excluded middle holds. -/
theorem LEMfromRetraction:
  (∀ {α β : Type} (g : α → β),
     Inhabited α → Function.Injective g → Function.HasLeftInverse g) →
  (∀ p : Prop, p ∨ ¬ p) := by
  intro H p
  obtain ⟨g,G⟩ := H (f p) ⟨.inl ()⟩ (f.injective p)
  have K : (g (.inr ()) = .inl ()) ∨ ∃ v, g (.inr ()) = .inr v :=
    by cases (g (.inr ())) <;> simp
  cases K
  case inl L =>
    apply Or.inr
    intro P
    have eq : .inr () = f p (.inr ⟨(), P⟩) := by rfl
    rw [eq, G (.inr ⟨(), P⟩)] at L
    contradiction
  case inr v =>
    obtain ⟨v, _⟩ := v
    apply Or.inl
    exact v.2

Your second suggestion is that a set is finite if it can be injected into a finite set. This too is a classical theorem because it implies excluded middle, see theorem 2.1 from my Five stages of accepting constructive mathematics.
